# Dealing with 3rd parties in create-react-app with react-native-web

Tags: react-native, create-react-app, react-native-web

We are trying to use the same React components both in mobile (react-native) and in web (create-react-app).

It's is working out pretty well so far thanks to [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) (configuration below).

However [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons), which we use extensively in the react-native project, does not compile with **react-native-web**. This means any component which uses a component with vector-icons will also need a specific web version. Having web specific versions of components effects maintenance.

Is there a known way, without having to eject create-react-app configuration, to deal with 3rd parties such as **react-native-vector-icons** in web?

```
import {createIconSetFromIcoMoon} from "react-native-vector-icons";

import Font from './Font.json';
export default createIconSetFromIcoMoon(UbeyaFont);
```

**Things we've thought of so far:** 
we are currently looking into two ideas:

- **Environment based import:**

  ```
  # Pseudo code:
  # if mobile import this, otherwise import that.
  ```

  We're not sure whether this kind of dynamic importing is possible
- **Webpack configuration** which is injected into **node_modules/react-scripts**. Not elegant but with a gulp watch which we have anyway we can make sure the configuration is always there.

Any ideas or thoughts are appreciated.

**Configuration:**
We've built a new private NPM package which holds all the React components and by using **gulp watch** that copies the package to both the mobile and web projects we save the trouble of constantly **npm publishing** and **yarning** during development (the only drawback Webstorm's indexing process).

Comment: What solution did you come across?

Comment: @InfinitePrime added the answer to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using a gulp script to overwrite webpack. The stages are:

**1) Build replacement packages**

We built a web version for **each** React Native 3rd party. For [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) it turned out to be quite simple:

```
    import React from 'react';

    export const Icon = (props) => <div className="material-icons" 
                                        style={{color:props.color}}>
        {props.name}
    </div>;


    export default Icon;
```

**2) Adjust the Webpack configuration**

Using gulp we overwrite the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) webpack configuration with:

```
 resolve: {
        modules: ...
        alias: {
            "babel-runtime": path.dirname(
                require.resolve("babel-runtime/package.json")
            ),
            "react-native": "@ourcompany/react-native-web",
            "react-native-vector-icons": "@ourcompany/react-native-vector-icons",
   ...
```

The gulp task script:

```
gulp.task("copyWebpack", function() {
    return gulp
        .src(["package.json", "src/_webpack/*.js"])
        .pipe(
            gulp.dest(
                path.resolve(pathWeb + "/node_modules/react-scripts/config")
            )
        );
});
```

Note:

- [Ejecting create-react-app's configuration](https://medium.com/@rodcisal/ejecting-and-adding-decorator-support-to-your-create-react-app-a4a7d80e4077) is cleaner, however it means you'll need to maintain the configuration and we preferred leaving the configuration as is and overwriting it during the build process.
- You'd notice we have overwritten react-native-web itself. More on this in the next optional step.

**3) Extend react-native-web (optional)**

If you are using components which [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) does not yet support, you would want to build packages for them and extend **react-native-web** so your web version will work. Simply create a new package **@yourcompany/react-native-web** and generate an **index.js** in which import the components that do exist in **react-native-web** and reference the ones you've built. Note that when we built our project **react-native-web** didn't have a FlatList or a SectionList and now (October 2018) it has both (Modal is still missing :-)).

```
import {
    StyleSheet as _StyleSheet,
    View as _View,
    Text as _Text,
    Image as _Image,
    I18nManager as _I18nManager,
    AsyncStorage as _AsyncStorage,
    Platform as _Platform,
    Linking as _Linking,
    ActivityIndicator as _ActivityIndicator,
    ListView as _ListView,
    Modal as _Modal,
    Picker as _Picker,
    RefreshControl as _RefreshControl,
    TextInput as _TextInput,
    Touchable as _Touchable,
    TouchableHighlight as _TouchableHighlight,
    TouchableNativeFeedback as _TouchableNativeFeedback,
    TouchableOpacity as _TouchableOpacity,
    TouchableWithoutFeedback as _TouchableWithoutFeedback,
    Dimensions as _Dimensions,
    Animated as _Animated,
    ScrollView as _ScrollView,
    SafeAreaView as _SafeAreaView,
    BackHandler as _BackHandler,
    Switch as _Switch,
    NetInfo as _NetInfo,
    AppState as _AppState,

    ColorPropType as _ColorPropType,
} from 'react-native-web';

import {SectionList as _SectionList} from './SectionList';
import {FlatList as _FlatList} from './FlatList';
import {Alert as _Alert} from './Alert';
import {WebView as _WebView} from './WebView';
import {Share as _Share} from './Share';
import {PermissionsAndroid as _PermissionsAndroid} from './PermissionsAndroid';
import {ActionSheetIOS as _ActionSheetIOS} from './ActionSheetIOS';
import {ToastAndroid as _ToastAndroid} from './ToastAndroid';

export const StyleSheet = _StyleSheet;
export const View = _View;
export const Text = _Text;
export const Image = _Image;
export const I18nManager = _I18nManager;
export const AsyncStorage = _AsyncStorage;
export const Platform = _Platform;
export const Linking = _Linking;
export const ActivityIndicator = _ActivityIndicator;
export const ListView = _ListView;
export const Modal = _Modal;
export const Picker = _Picker;
export const RefreshControl = _RefreshControl;
export const TextInput = _TextInput;
export const Touchable = _Touchable;
export const TouchableHighlight = _TouchableHighlight;
export const TouchableNativeFeedback = _TouchableNativeFeedback;
export const TouchableOpacity = _TouchableOpacity;
export const TouchableWithoutFeedback = _TouchableWithoutFeedback;
export const Dimensions = _Dimensions;
export const Animated = _Animated;
export const ScrollView = _ScrollView;
export const SafeAreaView = _SafeAreaView;
export const BackHandler = _BackHandler;
export const Switch = _Switch;
export const NetInfo = _NetInfo;
export const AppState = _AppState;

export const Alert = _Alert;
export const Share = _Share;
export const WebView = _WebView;
export const PermissionsAndroid = _PermissionsAndroid;
export const ActionSheetIOS = _ActionSheetIOS;
export const ToastAndroid = _ToastAndroid;

export const SectionList = _SectionList;
export const FlatList = _FlatList;

export const ColorPropType = _ColorPropType;
```